# QueueFeederThreads remain after python multiprocess Queue close()

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

(This is my first foray into python multiprocessing, so please anticipate copious newbie errors below, with my sincere apologies.)

I'm trying to ensure I have the underlying foundation of a python multiprocessing job structured correctly.  To do that, I've written the following simulation.  It assumes that each child worker is io-bound and I can have as many processes as required, even if that exceeds the number of cpu cores.  I start with a list of work ('drives') and create a child process and input queue for each unique 'drive'.  Each child then processes that 'drive', but may discover an additional 'drive' that needs to be fed back to the main line for dispatch to the appropriate child, using a fan-in results queue.

My question is:

When I run this in the VS Code IDE, I see the processes close, but a number of queuefeederthreads remain. Am I closing down the processes and queues correctly, or should I be explicitly calling close() and/or terminate()?

[image]

```
import time
import os
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Lock, JoinableQueue
from attrs import define, field

@define
class Finish:
    pass

@define
class Response:
    fromId: str = None
    data: str = None

@define
class NewScan:
    fromId: str = None
    toScan: str = None    

@define
class QueueReference:
    _responsesOutstanding: int = field(init=False, default=0)
    queue: Queue = None
    process: Process = None

    def _incrementOutstanding(self):
        self._responsesOutstanding += 1

    def _decrementOutstanding(self):
        self._responsesOutstanding -= 1   

        if self._responsesOutstanding < 0:
            print("Internal error: QueueReference.__responsesOutstanding <0")
            exit()

    def sendRequest(self, data):
        self._incrementOutstanding()
        self.queue.put(data)
        
 

def processor(inputQueue, resultQueue, consoleLock, drive):
    with consoleLock:
        print('Starting consumer => PID {}'.format(os.getpid()))
     
    while True:
        with consoleLock:
            print('PID {} waiting for data'.format(os.getpid()))

        dataToProcess = inputQueue.get()
 
        with consoleLock:
            print('PID {} processing {}'.format(os.getpid(), dataToProcess))

        if type(dataToProcess) is Finish:
            with consoleLock:
                print('PID {} exiting'.format(os.getpid()))

                inputQueue.close()
        
            exit()

        # simulate processing data

        time.sleep(random.randint(0, 2))

        if random.randint(0, 1) > 0.8:
            foundDrive = random.choice("ABCDEF") 
            resultQueue.put( NewScan(drive, foundDrive) )

        # time.sleep(random.randint(0, 10))
        resultQueue.put( Response(drive, "responsedata") )

        with consoleLock:
            print('PID {} finished {}'.format(os.getpid(), dataToProcess))
 
 

def main():
    requestsOutstanding = 0

    queueReferenceMap = dict()

    drives = ["A", "A", "B"]
 
    consoleLock = Lock()

     # Create the Queues

    resultQueue = Queue()     

    def processDrive(drive):
        nonlocal requestsOutstanding  # queueReferenceMap seems to work ok without this

        if drive not in queueReferenceMap.keys():
            queue = Queue()
            process = Process( target=processor, args=(queue, resultQueue, consoleLock, drive) )
            process.start()

            qr = QueueReference(queue, process)
            queueReferenceMap[drive] = qr
        else:
            qr = queueReferenceMap[drive]

        qr.sendRequest(drive)
        requestsOutstanding += 1

        with consoleLock:           
            print(f"New request, now {requestsOutstanding} requests outstanding")


    for drive in drives:   
        processDrive(drive)        

    while True:
        response = resultQueue.get()

        if type(response) is Response:
            requestsOutstanding -= 1

            with consoleLock:           
                print(f"Received response from {response.fromId}, data: {response.data}, now {requestsOutstanding} requests outstanding")    

            if requestsOutstanding == 0:
                # print( f"All requests processed" )
                break

        if type(response) is NewScan:
            with consoleLock:           
                print(f"Received request from {response.fromId} to scan {response.toScan}")

            processDrive(response.toScan)       

    with consoleLock:
        print( f"All requests processed" )

    for drive in queueReferenceMap.keys():
        print( f"{drive} -> {queueReferenceMap[drive]}" )
        queue = queueReferenceMap[drive].queue
        queue.put( Finish() )

    resultQueue.close()             

    print('Parent process exiting...')

    time.sleep(20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```